# How to push or create a new array with options and labels in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using react-select to implement a multi select dropdown. When I save the selected options to DB, I only save the selected options' value and not their labels by using:

```
Array.isArray(selectedOption)
? selectedOption.map((x) => x.value) : null
```

Now I am retrieving the data that is saved from the DB and inserting it back to the dropdown so that the dropdown can has an existing/default value.

This is what is saved in the DB: `staff,trainee`

In order for the dropdown to read the value, I need to make it into an array which I have done by using `.split(,)` which the string then becomes `['staff','trainee']` as an array.

[image]

Then, I need to make it so that the array will turn into
`[{value: 'staff', label: 'Staff'}, {value: 'trainee', label: 'trainee']` with the `value` and `label` in it. I also need to cater for if the value is only a single option and not a multiple selected options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `map` to create a new array like this:

```
const newArray = ['staff','trainee'].map(item => ({value: item, label: item}))
```

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I needed! Didn't know you can do that in ```map``` as well. Thank you for the prompt advice!